# derivedStateOf not working in conditional logic in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have simple compose function for counter logic. On counter logic I want to change float value. I tried some piece of code using `derivedStateOf` but it not working. Instead if I used simple condition logic it working fine.

```
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun Experiment() {
    Surface {
        var count by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
        ExperimentView(count) {
            count++
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ExperimentView(count: Int, onCountChange: () -> Unit) {
    Column {
        val floatValue by remember {
            derivedStateOf {
                if (count % 2 == 0) {
                    0.4F
                } else {
                    0.2F
                }
            }
        }
        Text(text = "$count with float value $floatValue")
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
        Button(onClick = { onCountChange() }) {
            Text(text = "Button")
        }
    }
}
```

Float value is never changing with the use of `derivedStateOf`. If I removed `derivedStateOf` it working fine. I am adding working example in below

```
@Composable
fun ExperimentView(count: Int, onCountChange: () -> Unit) {
    Column {
        val floatValue =
            if (count % 2 == 0) {
                0.4F
            } else {
                0.2F
            }

        Text(text = "$count with float value $floatValue")
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
        Button(onClick = { onCountChange() }) {
            Text(text = "Button")
        }
    }
}
```

So why this is happening in this code? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#derivedstateof), derivedStateOf should be used when you want to minimize recomposition for a value that can change more than you want. For example, a scroll position.
In your case, I believe the use case is making some recompositions not take effect.

You should also be aware that:

> Caution: derivedStateOf is expensive, and you should only use it to
> avoid unnecessary recomposition when a result hasn't changed.

In your example, you **want** the composable to recompose every time the counter changes, so using derivedStateOf is not a good case for this.

Answer (score 1):

Your `derivedStateOf` is not changing, because you don't read any `State` object during the calculation. From the documentation:

> ... reading `State.value` will cause all `State` objects that got read during the `calculation` to be read in the current `Snapshot` ...

You only read the function argument `count: Int` during the calculation, which is not a `State`.

Also, as already mentioned in previous answer, using `derivedStateOf` here is pointless.